# document.write stylesheet if statement that will always be false

Tags: javascript, html, css, stylesheet

While looking at some page's source, I found this Javascript code just below normal stylesheet definition:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if('' != '')
    {
        document.write("<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' />");
    }
</script>
```

Can someone enlighten me, what is (could be) the purpose of adding something like this to HTML page? Either I am lack of good big coffee this morning, or this part of Javascript is *never* executed and therefore this particular stylesheet is never added to the document.

So, what is the reason for adding such *thing* to HTML code? None (a mistake / error) or am I missing something really obvious?

Comment: I think it is a mistake.As this condition is always false and it will not include this style sheet.

Comment: Seems like it's for the developer's debugging. Simply placing another character like '' != 'a' would activate the script. Better than doing copy-paste all the time. But forgetting that it's there is... most likely what happened.

Comment: most likely a testing / editing orphan.

Comment: Someone just forgot to remove it after development mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one circumstance that this would make sense, though it is still probably messy - If the server would print a value there so that it it won't be equal, then the stylesheet will be used.

So, on the server in php, it might look like this:

```
echo "if('{$someVar}' != '')"
```

and if `$someVar` is an empty string, then you get the page source as you currently have it. Perhaps there is some circumstance where it is not empty. If in the code, `$someVar` could be given a value of (for example) `foo`, then the page source would say:

```
if('foo' != '')
    {
        document.write("<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' />");
    }
```

If this were the case, then it would make a lot more sense to go ahead and do the whole process on the server (noted in the comments below by user: still_learning).

```
if($someVar != '') echo "<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' />";
```

That does give more credit to the possibility that this was a simple on/off switch for a dev to use that wasn't removed. Simply removing the `!` would activate the stylesheet again.

Comment: Is there any reason why the comparison would be done client side rather than server side?

Comment: Possible, but why would anybody do that? Same thing without JavaScript: `if($someVar != '') echo "<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' />";`

Comment: @grc Yeah, bad coding :)

Comment: Right, it is bad coding, but it wouldn't surprise me.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this page comes from jsp or some template engine like freemarker, which need to compile source first to generate this result.

Answer (score 1):

This is never used because

```
'' != ''
```

will always return FALSE.

On the other hand the strings compared might have been outputted on the server side dynamically so you should see what's going on there first. Maybe this is not the only possible output and there are situations when the strings actually are different.

Although if that's the case I'd suggest to do the comparison on the server side too and only output the script if needed.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand this won't be executed because the condition is always false here. If this condition can be changed dynamically then we can think another scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

As you're looking at the page source, you might want to check the code.

```
if('' != '')
    {
        document.write("<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' />");
    }
```

If it is dynamic code, it might add css to page Or you can simply remove it as it will never add css to page.

Answer (score 1):

The script is not being executed on you side for sure.

But there can be a server side variables in the script that might be executed in some other case

For example

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if('<%=device%>' != '<%=mobile%>')
    {
        document.write("<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' />");
    }
</script>
```

where  `<%=device%>` and `<%=mobile%>` can be some server side variables

**NOTE- I used php for server side code it might be some other language**